# Vertx Kafka autocommit with explicit polling

Tags: java, apache-kafka, rx-java2, kafka-consumer-api, vert.x

Have been trying to write kafka consumer in java using Vertx.

I need to set the auto commit as false(specific use case).

Below is the code to do explicit polling

```
consumer.subscribe("test", ar -> {

if (ar.succeeded()) {
System.out.println("Consumer subscribed");

vertx.setPeriodic(1000, timerId -> {

  consumer.poll(100, ar1 -> {

    if (ar1.succeeded()) {

      KafkaConsumerRecords<String, String> records = ar1.result();
      for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
        KafkaConsumerRecord<String, String> record = records.recordAt(i);
        System.out.println("key=" + record.key() + ",value=" + record.value() +
          ",partition=" + record.partition() + ",offset=" + record.offset());
      }
    }
  });

});
```

}
});

And, to manually commit:

```
consumer.commit(ar -> {

 if (ar.succeeded()) {
 System.out.println("Last read message offset committed");
 }
 });
```

My question is that if the polling frequency is set to 1000ms and the commit is manual, what would happen if the message isn't processed within 1000ms?

Will the next poll be done before the first set of messages are processed ? If yes, will it again fetch the same set of message(which are not committed yet) or a newer set of messages?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of [`KafkaConsumer#poll`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#poll-java.time.Duration-):

> On each poll, consumer will try to use the last consumed offset as the starting offset and fetch sequentially. The last consumed offset can be manually set through seek(TopicPartition, long) or automatically set as the last committed offset for the subscribed list of partitions

The *last consumed offset* refers to the internal state of `KafkaConsumer`, not the one that it's committed. Which means that It won't fetch again the same messages, but it will fetch the next 100.